# Main.storyboard not connecting to viewcontroller.swift

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have kinda big problem:
When I add a view controller to my main.storyboard and then try to hook it up to viewcontroller.swift it won't connect, but my original one does how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you used the Identity Inspector to assign viewcontroller.swift to your new view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick guide for how to properly add a new View Controller.

1. Create a new ViewController.swift using the keyboard command `cmd`+`n`. Choose the Cocoa Touch Class
   [image: step 1]
2. Name it whatever you want & make sure it's a subclass of `UIViewController`
   [image: step 2]
3. Create and save the new .swift file. Now, copy the name of your view controller.
   [image: step 3]
4. In your storyboard, create a new view controller and select it.
   [image: step 4]
5. On the right hand side, under `Custom Class`, insert the new view controller's name (you should have copied that, so just hit paste) and hit enter
   [image]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you! this really helped!

Comment: You're totally welcome. Just make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Each View Controller in story board should have it`s own subclass of UIViewController. You can create new by pressing cmd + n -> Cocoa Class -> Subclass of "UIViewController".